# How to get a selected file from JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist, selectedindex, listselectionlistener

I have added a file named test.xml into my JList via JFileChooser using the below piece of code;

```
for (File file : fileChooser.getSelectedFiles()) {
   vector.addElement(file);
}
System.out.println("Added..!!");
list.updateUI();
```

And now I have to select a file from the Jlist and then convert it in to another document. The conversion step works if I give as input;

```
File file = new File("test.xml");
```

but it does not work if I give this;

```
for (int j : list.getSelectedIndices()) {
   File file = vector.elementAt(j);
   //-------code for conversion-------//
}
```

The list and its vector are created using the following piece of code :

```
                 vector = new Vector<File>(); 
                 final JList list = new JList(vector);    
                 scrollPane.setViewportView(list);"
```

can any of you please tell me how do I select that particula file from the JList in order to do the conversion?
Thanx in advance..!

Comment: @GuillaumePolet : I create my list and vector using          "vector = new Vector<File>();
  final JList list = new JList(vector);
  scrollPane.setViewportView(list);"

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I ahve edited my code adding the details of creating the jlist and vector(instead of defaultListModel).

Answer (score 4):

`JList` has the methods

```
public Object getSelectedValue()
public Object[] getSelectedValues()
```

Use them to get the files

Comment: Thank you but this does not solve my purpose since it needs to know that one particular file, for eg: 'test.xml' should be converted, hence I have to use the function "vector.elementAt(j)";

Comment: @dmurali: getSelectedValue() already return you the File instance to convert. If you also need to know it's index in vector you can use Vector method indexOf http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object,%20int%29

Comment: True, but in the next step, I have to parse the file(test.xml) using "Document doc = docBuilder.parse(file)" and this just accepts a file as an input and not anything else.

Comment: Now, I created '  for (Object j : list.getSelectedValues())                                     Document doc = docBuilder.parse(j);' but it gives an error since it cant parse 'j'

Comment: @dmurali simply cast `j` to a `File`. See my code in comments below that illustrates that!

Answer (score 4):

I have absolutely no issues with either the code suggested by StanislavL or by using your code. There must be something else in your code that you are not showing us. Here is an SSCCE showing that it works

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final Vector<File> files = new Vector<File>();
        final JList list = new JList(files);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(5);
        final JButton selectFile = new JButton("Select file...");
        selectFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
                fileChooser.showOpenDialog(selectFile);
                if (fileChooser.getSelectedFiles() != null) {
                    for (File file : fileChooser.getSelectedFiles()) {
                        files.add(file);
                    }
                    list.updateUI();
                }

            }
        });
        final JButton click = new JButton("Click me");
        click.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("The following files are selected in the list:\n");
                /*for (Object o : list.getSelectedValues()) {
                    sb.append(((File) o).getAbsolutePath()).append('\n');
                }*/
                for (int i : list.getSelectedIndices()) {
                    sb.append(files.get(i).getAbsolutePath()).append('\n');
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(click, sb.toString());
            }
        });
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(selectFile, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel.add(click, BorderLayout.EAST);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```